# Excel not capturing SUMIFS where condition is Text/Boolean

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sample data set with TRUE/FALSE values:

```
COLA   | COLB  | COLC 
------ | ----- | -----
ABCD   | 1234  | TRUE  
BCDE   | 2345  | FALSE
ABCD   | 3456  | TRUE
```

The formula which I'm attempting is `=SUMIFS(COLB,COLC,"TRUE",COLA,"ABCD")`, which is returning `0` instead of `4690`.

If I instead use Boolean denotation instead of Text `=SUMIFS(COLB,COLC,TRUE,COLA,"ABCD")`, it still returns a `0`.

Oddly enough, if I go back to the cells in COLC and double click + enter on the values, the contents get centered and then the formula starts working correctly:

```
COLA   | COLB  | COLC 
------ | ----- | -----
ABCD   | 1234  |  TRUE  
BCDE   | 2345  | FALSE
ABCD   | 3456  |  TRUE
```

However, I don't want to do this because the data is being imported via a macro and the sheet shouldn't be touched.

How can I fix the formula to capture the text as it is currently in COLC?

Comment: Try with this =SUMIFS(COLB,COLC,TRUE())

Comment: @Nicolaesse No joy :(

Comment: Your formulas work. I believe it is an issue in the format type of COLC `=SUMIFS(B3:B5,A3:A5,"ABCD",C3:C5,"TRUE")`

Comment: The problem is with the data and not the formula.  Some is being viewed as text others the boolean.  You will need to fix the data as it is coming in.

Comment: You could use `=ISLOGICAL(C2)` to verify if your data is formatted as boolean (in that case this formula return true). Let us know your result.

Comment: You can add a secondary column with `=C3="TRUE"`, and then run the SUMIFS using that new column instead of C.

Comment: That's indeed the issue. During the data import, the fist row's value is blank so Excel is not considering the column to be Boolean. How can I set it as such during the import process in the macro?

Comment: That is a different question, please pose a new question with examples of your raw data and the code used to bring in the values.  I would remove this one as it is not the formula that is in error but the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SUMIFS` is interpreting the `TRUE` in the criteria argument as Boolean.  Your data is being imported as a text string.

You can force SUMIFs to view TRUE as a string by adding a wild card:

```
=SUMIFS(COLB,COLA,"ABCD",COLC,"*TRUE")
```

Obviously, not ideal, as it will count any string that ends with TRUE, but should work given your example.

An alternative, not dependent on wild cards is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COLA="ABCD")*(COLC="TRUE")*COLB)
```

If you need to be able to count TRUE whether it might be BOOLEAN or TEXT, try one of these:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(COLB,COLA,"ABCD",COLC,{"*TRUE",TRUE}))
=SUMPRODUCT((COLA="ABCD")*(COLC={"TRUE",TRUE})*COLB)
```